# Is there a limit of requests that an Apache server can make and wait for response?

Tags: web-development, performance, apache

Let say I have an Apache server that needs data from external API before serving the page. I wonder if there is a limit of requests an Apache server can make and wait for response. Or does it depend on the physical server?

Comment: see [Where does my tool question go?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7253/where-does-my-tool-question-go)

Comment: @gnat Isn't this question going beyond simple tool support ? Isn't it about technical constraints that affect a more complex architecture (i.e. broadly open source Apache+another system) and therefore of interest for many SW-engineer working with web architectures ?

Comment: Is your API a remote web service ?  Or is it a callable API on your local system ?

Comment: @Christophe yes, it is a remote web service

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. its not so much the outgoing request though. Its keeping all the incoming requests hanging around while you wait.

https://serverfault.com/questions/796968/apache-2-4-max-concurrent-users-limit

Comment: Interesting and accurate link !  Could you nevertheless elaborate a little more on the limiting factors in order to make your answer more specific to the question and bring more value than a link-only contribution ?

Comment: not really, the question is so broad. It will probably be closed as off topic and I will get downvotes for daring to have answered it